# Display stack trace in Android Studio - it's disappeared

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, stack-trace

Very dumb, very basic question, but this has been frustrating the hell out of me, so here goes.

My stack trace has disappeared in Android Studio. All Logcat shows is crap like this:

```
8:34:36 PM Gradle build finished in 16 sec
8:41:30 PM Gradle build finished in 10 sec
8:43:05 PM Gradle build finished in 8 sec
8:43:07 PM Session 'app': running
8:45:18 PM Gradle build finished in 10 sec
8:45:20 PM Session 'app': running
```

No stack trace, no nothing, and I know for sure that there are exceptions I should be seeing. What do I do? How do I get my beautiful stack trace to come back to me? I've been researching this for half an hour and nothing I've found so far seems to help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This log aren't Logcat, this is Event Log

To turn on Logcat go View > Tool Windows > Android Monitor (Alt + 6 on Windown or Command + 6 on OSX)

Comment: I can't see any "Android Monitor" in Tool Windows. When I hit Command + 6, all it does is toggle between showing Event Log and not showing it. Could there be something wrong with my installation?

Comment: @jpabene, Is in your screen show this view ? http://imgur.com/TIt2gMV or http://imgur.com/70CHVqw

Comment: http://imgur.com/mmILCIt It displays this at the bottom. Instead of "Android Monitor" my screen simply says "Android"

Comment: Why you did not choose "Android" and turn off Event Log ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When I click "Android" nothing at all happens.

Comment: I have discovered what was wrong. It is entirely related to me being a BIG F*CKING IDIOT. Thank you very much, you've been extremely helpful!

Comment: Just share what wrong? You will help another user :D

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty embarrassing, but I made the mistake, so I'll own up to it. I had the damn thing shrunk so tiny that I couldn't see it. All I had to do was drag the window out to open it up.