# When add "list.setAdapter(adapter) to my onCreate, app crashes. Ideas why?

Tags: android-studio

I've made a new project that contains a RelativeLayout with a ListView as a child.  I need to add the items of an array to the ListView.  I've done a lot of searches looking for answers on my own but as best I can tell, I'm doing the same thing as what I've seen in the examples that I've read.  So I'm really confused as to where I went wrong.

This is the onCreate method of my activity.  When I comment out the line that calls setAdapter (marked in the code with a comment), the app loads fine (but it just doesn't display the list items).  If I do NOT comment this out and run it through the debugger, I see that the code does actually continue well past this line -- deep into the base *.java files before the app crashes.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_transaction);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    String[] myItems = {"Mark Johnson","Joe Smith","John Doe","James MacArthy"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.txnlayout,myItems);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.txnListView); 
    list.setAdapter(adapter); //  <---comment out this line and the app loads fine.

}
```

The activity_transaction contains the following ListView.

```
    <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txnListView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:clickable="false"/>
```

I've continued to attempt to troubleshoot this and since it does continue past this line, I looked at the value of the ListView object AFTER the setAdapter line.  I see that it did in fact add the items from the arrayList -- that's what I assume the adapter is supposed to do --correct?

[image]

The logcat follows below.  I see a line in there about the ArrayAdapter needing a TextView.  This is the contents of txnlayout.xml (the ArrayAdapter points to this file).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txnListViewItem"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the logcat.

```
12-09 19:24:16.997: W/Resources(28062): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f0d0055}
12-09 19:24:16.997: W/Resources(28062): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f0d0056}
12-09 19:24:17.047: W/Resources(28062): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f090084 a=-1 r=0x7f090084}
12-09 19:24:17.057: W/Resources(28062): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f0d0069}
12-09 19:24:17.057: W/Resources(28062): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1 a=3 r=0x7f08000f}
12-09 19:24:17.057: W/Resources(28062): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1 a=3 r=0x7f08000e}
12-09 19:24:17.057: W/Resources(28062): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x3801 a=1 r=0x10500cb}
12-09 19:24:17.067: W/Resources(28062): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1001 a=3 r=0x7f080019}
12-09 19:24:17.067: W/Resources(28062): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1001 a=3 r=0x7f08004c}
12-09 19:24:17.067: W/Resources(28062): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1001 a=3 r=0x7f080019}
12-09 19:24:17.067: W/Resources(28062): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1001 a=3 r=0x7f08004c}
12-09 19:24:17.067: W/Resources(28062): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f0d006a}
12-09 19:24:17.077: D/AbsListView(28062): Get MotionRecognitionManager
12-09 19:24:17.097: D/MoneyBox(28062): [Ljava.lang.String;@346af6ff
12-09 19:24:17.097: D/MoneyBox(28062): android.widget.ListView{31070ccc VFED.VC. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0d006a app:id/txnListView}
12-09 19:24:17.097: D/MoneyBox(28062): android.widget.ArrayAdapter@37aecb15
12-09 19:24:17.097: D/Activity(28062): performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
12-09 19:24:17.097: D/Activity(28062): performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
12-09 19:24:17.107: D/OpenGLRenderer(28062): Render dirty regions requested: true
12-09 19:24:17.137: W/Resources(28062): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f0d007f}
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/ArrayAdapter(28062): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
12-09 19:24:17.137: D/AndroidRuntime(28062): Shutting down VM
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062): Process: com.iresoft.moneybox, PID: 28062
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2823)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1290)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1202)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:610)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:677)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2897)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2248)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1306)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1548)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6642)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
12-09 19:24:17.137: E/AndroidRuntime(28062):    ... 50 more
```

Comment: Could you please add your logcat when app crash ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in layout activity_transaction you have Listview with id txnListView

Comment: Yep -- it's there.  Thanks.     <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txnListView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:clickable="false"/>

Comment: Post your logcat when app crash please

Comment: I attempted to get a logcat for you.  But Logcat Extreme (that's what I've got on my phone) is telling me there's nothing related to my app.  I cleared the log, ran my app (watched it crash) and checked logcat.  Nadda.  Is there anyway to get some kind of log from the AS debugger?

Comment: Check this. If you dont have logcat, we cannot know what bug to fix? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684710/display-stack-trace-in-android-studio-its-disappeared/33684765#33684765

Comment: I understand about needing info to be able to help.  My last question was more about HOW to find the info you were asking for.  I was able to figure out how to get it to filter the output.  I'll update the question to show the logcat info.